Gnus with OAuth2 authentication
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use xoauth2 authentication with Gnus.
I succeeded in getting an OAuth2 access token with oauth2.el and storing it in file oauth2-token-file. But how do I tell Gnus to use this token?
I have this configuration:
(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "GMail"
           (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
           (nnimap-user "XXX@gmail.com")
           (nnimap-stream ssl)
           (nnimap-authenticator xoauth2)
           ))

But Gnus tries to find a password in authinfo.gpg. How should I tell Gnus to use the OAuth2 token in oauth2-token-file?
